# How to set web version as default in blogger

Tags: html, blogger

I am currently working on a project and i have custom html edit on my blogger but when I open the same blog in my mobile it shows the simple blog template and shows a button to view web version. Is there any way where i can set desktop version as default

Answer (score 0):

Theme > Choose mobile theme > mobile_friendly

Do you want to show the Desktop or Mobile theme on mobile devices?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a empty post.
change the edit format to html.
Remove every thing there, Paste it there with your link
" Click here if you are on mobile. "

Mine works!